# How to forecast count based on a day?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am new to SQL Server world. I have a table as below:

```
alert_id | create_date | Status
---------+-------------+---------
1231     | 4/15/2017   | Open
1232     | 4/15/2017   | Open
1234     | 4/15/2017   | Closed
1235     | 4/16/2017   | Open
```

All of these alerts should be closed in 30 days. I need to get a forecast report which shows how many alerts are open for past 30 days.

I would like to write a select query whose output would be 2 columns. First would be Date and 2nd would be count. The date column should display all the dates for next 30 days and Count column should display the number of records which are due to expire on that day. Something like below would work. Please assist.

```
date      |   Count
----------+---------
5/15/2017 |  2
5/16/2017 |  3
5/17/2017 |  0
5/18/2017 |  0
.
.
.
6/14/2017 |  0
```

Comment: your are using sql-server  or mysql ?... remove wrong tag and the right one

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `GROUP BY` and date arithmetic.  In MySQL:

```
SELECT DATE(create_date) + INTERVAL 30 DAY expire_date, COUNT(*) num
  FROM tbl
 WHERE status = 'Open'
 GROUP BY DATE(create_date)
```

`DATE(create_date) + INTERVAL 30 DAY` gets you the create date values with thirty days added.

`GROUP BY(create_date)` groups your data by values of your create date, truncated to midnight.

And, `COUNT(*)` goes with `GROUP BY` to tell you how many records in each group.

**Edit** In recent versions of SQL Server (MS)

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 30, CAST(create_date AS DATE)) expire_date, COUNT(*) num
  FROM tbl
 WHERE status = 'Open'
 GROUP BY CAST(create_date AS DATE)
```

Notice, please, that date arithmetic varies between make and model of SQL server software. That's why you get hassled by Stack Overflow users in comments when you use more than one tag like [oracle] [mysql] [sql-server] on your questions.

Cool, huh?  You should read up on aggregate queries, sometimes called summary queries.

You're not going to get the missing dates with zeros by them. That's quite a bit harder to do with SQL.

Comment: I am using sql-server. When tried above approach, it error out with "'DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: looks like below query gives me the desired output for the "date" column but I am not sure how to join this with create_date to retrieve the required data for 2nd column. <br/>
    select dateadd(d, number, getdate()-1) as [date] from 
    master..spt_values where type='p' and number between 1 and 30;

Comment: any help is appreciated.